# Mail.app refuses to send e-mail

Tags: mail.app, email, certificate

I have just upgraded to Monterey (12.0.1 (21A559)), and cannot send e-mails.  Mail.app tells me that the certificate is not valid.

We own our own domain and host the primary MX here, and this worked on my previous Mac.

It is actually a real certificate obtained from a *bona fide* registrar, and it works fine in our web server.  But I guess it has to be modified in some way to be a mail server certificate.

Alternatively, can I accept the certificate permanently?  If so, how as the option to do is currently greyed out.

Incidentally, it's the same on my iPhone and iPad - can receive mails but cannot send them.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.  I hadn't looked closely enough, and the cert expired in 2018.  Grabbed the certs from my web server, scp'em them to the mx, and configured sendmail.

Fixed!